# In a Cox PH regression, how to include an independent time variable that may or may not have occurred (right censored)?

Tags: data-transformation, cox-model

In a cox regression to build an internally validated predictive model, one of the variables that is important is whether event x occurred (yes/no). In addition, I am being asked to consider is whether time to event x can be included. How best to code this?

```
# y is dependent variable, yt is time to event y 
# x is independent variable, xt is time to event x 
# a,b,c are various independent variables

library(Hmisc) 
library(rms) 
S <- Surv(yt, y==1) units(y) <- "months" 
dd <= datadist (data); options(datadist="dd")

cph ~ (S ~ a + b + c + x + xt)
```

However, xt contains missing values ( for those who never reached x, or x = 0 ). It would be wrong to code them as zeroes. In reality, some of those xt are infinity as x never occurred. What should I do? Help is much appreciated.